# Rotate the text inside a small grid/panel

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid, label, stackpanel

```
<Label Grid.Row="1"
       Height="70"
       Margin="2"
       Width="300"
       Content="{l:Translate Key={x:Static l:MultistringTags.SHOW_MENU}}"
       DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
       FontSize="20"
       FontWeight="Bold"
       Foreground="White">
       <Label.RenderTransform>
           <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
       </Label.RenderTransform>
</Label>
```

Here I want to rotate the text, which is inside a grid and a grid column width equals with text height. In this case I see only part of text like if text was drawn without rotating cutted of by grid width, and rotated to required angle. I have tried panels, they give me same result.

Does anybody know some workaround to make it show all the text and I don't want to use image because text should be translatable.

Comment: You could try to replace the label with a textblock that has the textwrapping property, or even put the textblock inside your label

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe if you change it to set the `LayoutTransform` instead of `RenderTransform`, it will prevent the text from being cut off.

```
        <Label.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
        </Label.LayoutTransform>
```

Comment: Thanks, your response was really helpful.

Comment: @VladimirKruglov If it solved your problem, please be sure to mark it as an answer to help others who see this question in the future =)

Answer (score 1):

Further to @nekizalb's answer stating that you should use a `LayoutTransform`, the reason that you would need to do that instead of using a `RenderTransform` is because of the timing at which each occurs... a `LayoutTransform` will affect results of layout.

From the [`UIElement.RenderTransform` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx) page on MSDN:

> A render transform does not regenerate layout size or render size information. Render transforms are typically intended for animating or applying a temporary effect to an element. For example, the element might zoom when focused or moused over, or might jitter on load to draw the eye to that part of the user interface (UI).

From the [`FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN:

> In contrast to RenderTransform, LayoutTransform will affect results of layout.
>
> Example scenarios where LayoutTransform would be useful include: rotating elements such as menu components from horizontal to vertical or vice versa, scaling elements (zooming in) on focus, providing editing behavior, etc.